# Active Directory Incorrect password attempts double counting

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using the following C# code to connect to active directory and validate the login,

```
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(); 
    string username = "myuser", path = "LDAP://addev2.dev.mycompany.com/CN=myuser,DC=dev,DC=mycompany,DC=com", password = "test";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4;i++ )
    {

        try
        {

            de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Sealing | AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.FastBind;
            de.Username = username;
            de.Password = password;

            de.Path = path;

      //de.RefreshCache();
            Object obj = de.NativeObject;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

this works fine when the password is correct. However when the password is incorrect this shows as 2 invalid attempts in AD.
So what happens is when the AD admin allows 5 invalid attempts the user is locked out on the 3rd attempt.
when i look in the AD's event log 1 see 2 entries.

1)Pre-authentication failed:

2)Logon attempt by:

```
MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
     Logon account: m0707b@dev.mycompany.com
     Source Workstation: WKSXXXX
     Error Code:    0xC000006A
```

Stepping thro the code i see 2 event entries on the line

```
  de.RefreshCache()
```

I tried using de.NativeObject to see if that would solve the problem. No Dice

Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this perplexing issue when you use the format username@domain the IIS app uses 2 calls once using Kerebros and when that fails using NTLM causing a double count The fix is to use the following format for authentication domain\username and that fixed the issue.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264678/EN-US/

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace. You can access an account and then cast one of the methods it has into a DirectoryEntry object. It might get around your double-authentication problem and it's easier to use.